# Series of SQL/DML/DDL commands and Syntax for running in DBMS

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a small question, but what is the name for a series of SQL/ DML / DDL commands stored in a file? Also, what is the syntax for running this file in DBMS?

Comment: I simple search in a search engine does not quite fulfil this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `help` command in `mysql` refers to it as a SQL script file. The syntax for running it in MySQL from the shell is:

```
mysql ..options.. < filename
```

e.g.

```
mysql -u username -p databasename < filename.sql
```

See the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html) for details of using the `mysql` command-line tool.

You can also run it from within the `mysql` command with:

```
mysql>source filename
```

or

```
mysql>. filename
```

I don't use phpMyAdmin, so I don't know if there's a way to do it from there.

Comment: Do you know if this is completely correct? Perhaps you can specify more than one example. Also, It is, indeed possible to run commands from DBMS.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "run commands from DBMS". This is how I always run SQL scripts.